# Search for keywords in PDF independent of upper and lower case

Tags: python, full-text-search

I want to search for keywords in multiple PDF Documents. How could I achieve it, that upper and lower case is not considered, so for example if there is written 'lineare Gleichungssysteme' instead of 'Lineare Gleichungssysteme' it is also counted as a match?

```
# import packages
import PyPDF2
import re
import os, sys


dirs_list=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        dirs_list.append(dirs)

dirs_list=dirs_list[-1]
dirs_list.pop(0)
#print(dirs_list)


for k in dirs_list:

data_names=os.listdir(k)
data_names.pop(0)

for j in data_names:
    # open the pdf file
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(os.path.join(k, j))

    # get number of pages
    num_pages = len(reader.pages)

    # define key terms
    strings = ['Lineare Gleichungen','Quadratische Gleichungen']
    total=len(strings)

    counter=0
    # extract text and do the search
    for page in reader.pages:
        for i in strings:
            text = page.extract_text() 
            #print(type(i))
            res_search = re.search(i, text)
            if res_search != None:
                counter+=1
            #print(res_search)
    
    print(j, counter/total)
```

Does someone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, click the arrow button next to “Find” command under “Home” tab. Then click “Advanced Find” to open the “Find and Replace” box. Next place cursor at the “Find what” text box. Enter “[A-Z]{2,}” to find all words with all letter capitalized.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).